# Python map with default arguments

Tags: python

Suppose I have some function which takes default arguments:

```
def fn(foo=0,bar=1):
    return something
```

How do I create a map and specify which default arguments, in pseudocode:

```
map(fn,foo=[1,2,3])
```

or:

```
map(fn,bar=[5,6,7])
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is not mapping a function on an iterable but somehow trying to pass parameters to the function.

Comment: @SimeonVisser is there a difference?

Comment: Yes, because `map()` wasn't intended to have the argument passed to different keyword parameters. If you would always pass the numbers to `foo` and you'd have `bar=1` as parameter with default argument then we'd have a valid use of `map()`.

Comment: @MikeVella, you accepted mtitan8 answer, but in my view it gives not the output asked by your question and pseudo code. Please clarify what exactly did you want to achieve (see my answer for example, when output of sample fn is provided)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `lambda` to wrap the function with the default parameters:

```
map(lambda x: fn(x, bar=[1, 2, 3]), range(5))
```

Comment: Thanks, There were several excellent answers but I found yours to be my preferred one because it relies on no external modules and just "feels" right.

Comment: @Kevin: good point, I updated my answer to use `fn` as the function instead.

Answer (score 5):

For sake of correctnes, it seems that `partial` usage should be

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def fn(foo=0,bar=1):
...     print 'foo {}, bar {}'.format(foo, bar)
...
>>> foo = [1,2,3]
>>> bar = [4,5,6]
>>> map(fn, foo)
foo 1, bar 1
foo 2, bar 1
foo 3, bar 1
[None, None, None]
>>> map(partial(fn, 0), bar)
foo 0, bar 4
foo 0, bar 5
foo 0, bar 6
[None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use list comprehension I think

```
[foo(bar=i) for i in [1,2,3]]
```

as for map the only way I can propose You is function  which will call your function with expected keyword argument

either dedicated function

```
def wrapper(func, kw):
    def wrapped(a):
        return func(**{kw: a})
    return wrapped

map(wrapper(foo, 'bar'), [1, 2, 3]) # if keyword argument is the same far all calls
```

or lambda

```
map(lambda x: foo(bar=x), range(5)) # if keyword argument is the same far all calls  

map(lambda x: foo(**{y:x}), ['bar', 'foo', 'bar'], range(3)) # if keyword arguments are different all calls
```

Comment: List comprehension hits a snag for me because I want to multi-thread this map.